# Is it possible to pause an InputStream, to let other threads access it for a moment?

Tags: java, multithreading

Imagine this Runnable class in it's own thread :

```
private Socket _socket;

public void run() // its own thread
{
    while(true)
        print(_socket.getInputStream().read());
}
```

then imagine somewhere else in the code, a different thread needs to use the same socket to send and receive something real quick:

```
public static int askSomething(Socket socket)
{
    socket.getOutputStream().write(SOMETHING);
    socket.getOutputStream().flush();
    return _socket.getInputStream().read();
}
```

What happens in this scenario is that `askSomething` will send `SOMETHING` to the remote machine, but the main runnable class would steal the answer and print it first, thus, `askSomething` method would just timeout or hang.

How can this be solved without having to rewrite everything ? I mean is there any possible way to pause the first InputStream until I'm done with it ?

Comment: No. Something is seriously wrong with your design here.

Comment: You can interrupt the first thread, release the InputStream in the handling for the interrupt and then run it again once `askSomething` has done its business. Kind of a hacky way.

Comment: @aa333: would that be possible and safe while it's being blocked by ".read()" ?

Comment: Unsafe if multiple threads try to interrupt at the same time.

Comment: @aa333 No you can't. Socket I/O isn't interruptible unless you use SocketChannels, and if you do the interrupt closes the channel. 'Release the InputStream' doesn't actually mean anything.

Comment: @Heidi The real question here is why you do have the thread continuously reading the socket in the first place? You have to make up your mind. Either the server is delivering a continuous byte-stream *or* it implements a request-response protocol. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to build an out-of-bound messaging system on top of your primary.  You really have to build it into the same code that pumps out messages..

Comment: @seand I assume you mean 'out of band'?

Comment: @EJP thanks for catching, yes I meant to say "out of band"